# There has been a timeout failure or the job got stuck. Check your timeout limits or try again in COMPILE STAGE

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I get this message and my runner is working btw. so what can be the problem here?
[image]

This is the error I get
From this
[image]
TO THIS :(
[image]

the .gitlab-ci.yml is working btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We reinstalled and updated the runners and reconfigured them again and after restarting the server it worked. I am not sure what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your job was still running when the GitLab job timeout was reached.
You can adjust the timeout settings in `Settings >> CI/CD >> General pipelines`.

https://git.qwant.ninja/help/ci/pipelines/settings#set-a-limit-for-how-long-jobs-can-run

Comment: the timeout was set on 2 hours and the default was 1hour but still, it was still not working. Anyways, we solved the problem later. Thank you ^^